# Neo4j cypher merge with on create object properties not matching

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm wondering if there is another way of doing this since it's clearly not working when I try to set a group of properties with an object.

An example is that I create a reference node `create (t:Reference {name: 'reference'})` .

Then I'm receiving, say a number of properties, which I want to set in a node that has a relationship with `Reference` node.

`match (ref:Reference)
where ref.name = 'reference'
with ref
merge (t:Test {uuid: '123'})-[:merge_test]->(ref)
on create set t = {name1: 'a name', name2: 'another name'}, t.created = timestamp(), t.updated = timestamp()
on match set t.updated = timestamp()
return t`

You would think that running the above cypher 2 times, the first would initially create it, and the second time around it would only update the `updated` property of t:Test, however this is not the case, a new one is created each time as if the merge never never detected the `uuid` match.

I've removed the `t = {name1: 'a name', name2: 'another name'}` from the `on create` and it works as expected, that is the second run will update the `updated` property and not create a new `:Test` node. IE:

`match (ref:Reference)
where ref.name = 'reference'
with ref
merge (t:Test {uuid: '123'})-[:merge_test]->(ref)
on create set t.name1 = 'a name', t.name2 = 'another name', t.created = timestamp(), t.updated = timestamp()
on match set t.updated = timestamp()
return t`

But this doesn't work for me since I'm receiving a mixed set of properties, without timestamps, in my collection and wanted to set it with t = {my_main_properties} collection.

Wondering if this is a bug in Cypher or did I completely miss something in the documentation? If either what would be a workaround?

Using Neo4j 2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

I think I just understood what's going on here, the created phase of this operation won't set the uuid, therefore the second time around it will be created again. So it's as if:

`on create set t = { params }`

wipes out the properties defined in the merge:

`merge (t:Test {uuid: '123'})-[:...`

here the uuid is wiped out by the on create.

A workaround is to also define it in the `params` object.

Comment: and there is also `t += {params}`